# ¿Cómo se genera la numeración aleatoria?

Tags: algoritmos, matemáticas, lenguaje-agnóstico

[image: Dados aleatorios]

Ejemplo; en los siguientes lenguajes yo puedo llamar las siguientes funciones y en cada llamada me devolverán un número diferente:

- **PHP:** [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php).
- **Js:** [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random).

Pero lejos de referenciar estos dos lenguajes (o cualquier otro), me surgen las siguientes dudas:

- ¿Cómo el ordenador realiza dicha operación?
- ¿Qué algoritmo o base matemática utiliza para generarlos?

Comment: El problema de esta pregunta es que tiene una respuesta distinta por cada lenguaje.. el codigo de random de C# es libre.

Comment: Muchos de estas funciones usan valores como el tiempo actual en milisegundos (11515525154187) para crear valores aleatorios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP rand (), como todos los generadores de números aleatorios, no genera datos verdaderamente aleatorios, sino que utiliza alguna función matemática para crear datos aparentemente aleatorios.

Los métodos pueden variar, pero el principio básico es este: tomamos un valor inicial como 'semilla', `s`. (Esta puede ser la hora actual, un valor "aleatorio" ingresado por el usuario, etc.)

Luego tomamos `s` aplicamos una función, `f`, para producir un nuevo valor `s'`(s-prima) (esta función es a menudo una función de módulo o hash).

Luego podemos repetir este proceso hasta el infinito, poner `s'` en `f'` produciendo `s''` (s-prima 2), etc. Esta secuencia de resultados de `f` son nuestros números "aleatorios".

Pero, es de esperar que te hayas dado cuenta, `f` permaneció igual y siempre producirá la misma salida con la misma entrada. Entonces, si le damos las mismas semillas iniciales, siempre obtendremos la misma secuencia de `s'`, `s''`, `s'''`...

Por eso los llamamos "Psuedo" al azar. Si no conoces la semilla inicial y no observas la secuencia por mucho tiempo, parece aleatorio. Pero si conocemos la función `f` utilizada y las semillas iniciales, podemos predecir cada valor que `rand()` producirá.

Este es un artículo bastante interesante del tema - http://cod.ifies.com/2008/05/php-rand01-on-windows-openssl-rand-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Quiere decir eso que una máquina no puede crear un número aleatorio porque siempre parte de un valor inicial? Si nosotros conocemos ese valor inicial o semilla y el algoritmo de la función "f", podemos predecir en el 100% de los eventos, qué número "aleatorio" te va a generar el programa.

Comment: Hola Ganaya,  esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!, por otro lado, fijate que estás comentnado una pregunta que fue hecha hace cuatro años! ;).